# Delphi and XQuery/XPath 2.0?

Tags: delphi, xpath, xquery

How do people use XQuery and/or XPath 2.0 from Delphi? I've got MSXML v6.0 working from Delphi, so any sufficiently documented COM-implementation will work. What's your favorite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**My Favourite:** I've always found that importing [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760399(VS.85).aspx) provides excellent support for all the XPath queries I've ever needed it for.

**Close second:** I'm not aware of any native delphi libraries that can match MSXML's depth of features however [OmniXML](http://www.omnixml.com/) provides great support for basic XPath queries and if you're not using expressions, for example, then it's a pretty good alternative.

Sadly, I do not think that there are currently any native Delphi XML Libraries that fully support XPath 2.0.

Comment: Thanks jamiei, I'm pretty impressed with MSXML so far (despite my personal feelings for M$). Sad, though, that it doesn't support XPath 2.0. Haven't had time to look at OmniXML yet.

Comment: Indeed, conciliator, I'm not sure that there is a native delphi library that fully supports XPath 2.0! Sad times indeed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fast and opensource [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) library. There is a [Sourceforge Project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libxml2-pas/) for free Delphi bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I love OmniXML. It has a lot of supporting code and classes that extend its primary usage. You may also want to look at [SimpleStorage](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/simplestorage/) that simplifies work with XML a lot.